# Support non-exact snapshots

Tags: jestjs

I'm working on a test suite for a build tool and I'm finding that I'm wasting quite a bit of time updating what are essentially manual snapshots like the following:

```js
export const defaultBuild = {
    'bundle.abcde.js': 1000,
    'bundle.abcde.css': 112,
}
```

The idea here being that we do want to catch changes in file hash and changes in the file size beyond +/- 5%. But, every time one of these do change, it's a manual effort to go and rewrite these. As there are a couple dozen entries in reality, this is rather time consuming. Ideally, I'd like to switch this over to use Jest's snapshot tests, as (importantly), they can be updated with a flag. Much quicker!

Now, I'm easily able to support testing stable file hashes. A little bit of `readdir` manipulation gets me a stringified directory structure and all is good. The part I'm struggling with is the directory sizes though. It really is quite important that +/- 5% be acceptable, else the snapshots will be updating almost constantly and be too noisy. But, from what I can tell, Jest offers to custom comparator for the snapshot testing. It's exact matches only.

Is there any good method out there for storing something like file sizes in a snapshot so they can be auto-updated, but also allowing some wiggle room?

To give an idea of where I've started:

```js
expect.extend({
    // Pending more thoughtful name
    toSortaMatchSnapshot(dir) {
        const lines = dir.split('\n');

        for (const line of lines) {
            const match = line.match(/(^[^:]*):\s([0-9]*)/);
            if (match) {
                let fileName = match[1].trim();
                if (/\.\w{5}/.test(fileName)) {
                    fileName = fileName.replace(/\.\w{5}/, '');
                }
                const fileSize = Number(match[2]);

                const expectedMin = fileSize * 0.95;
                const expectedMax = fileSize * 1.05;

                //const message = (comparator, val) =>
                //  `expected '${fileName}' to be ${comparator} than ${val}, but it's ${receivedSize}`;

                // This won't really ever work
                toMatchSnapshot.call(this, fileSize, fileName);
            }
        }

        return {
            message: () => '',
            pass: true,
        };
    },
});
```

Example input would look something like this:

```
`build
  bundle.abcde.js: 1000
  bundle.abcde.css: 112
`;
```

Comment: Why not parse to an object, then you could just use `.toMatchObject` and e.g. https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/number/#tobewithinstart-end

Comment: Parsing's no problem, it's the issue of how can you automatically update those snapshots with `-u` when they exceed +/- 5%? That's the pain point I'm trying to fix, manually updating the sizes.